Concurrency Control Mechanism For Dataframe Processing In Django WebApp
I have django webapp where processing excel file data directly using pandas dataframe. now, I want to make this operations concurrency control for multiple request processing simultaneously. suggest me best approach for it. I am aware about atomic transactions in django but it is not useful for the pandas processing.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
